# Wireless Network Mode from N-only to Mixed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I had to set up the Wireless Network Mode signal on my router-wifi from N-Only to Mixed (the other options are: B-only, G-Only, BG-Mixed, NG-mixed). That's because a wifi controller on a pretty old PC didn't connect to my router-wifi device.

The WiFi card in the old computer is a **Qualcomm Atheros AR5005G Wireless Network Adapter**.

I am anything but an network expert and I was wondering whether this changing can affect my wifi signal badly somehow. First, how can I find out in which mode the "old wifi controller works with? If, just for instance, it works in G-mode, would it be better to set that wifi option in NG-Mixed?

Please help me to figure this out and how it works? Thanks

Comment: Is the controller built in to the motherboard? What is the make an model of the old PC? If it is separate wireless card what is the make and model of the card?

Comment: @DavidPostill. I forgot to say that it is a separate wireless card.

Comment: Network Connections should show the make and model of the wireless card in the Device Name Column.

Comment: @DavidPostill. It's a Qualcomm Atheros AR5005G Wireless Network Adapter. It seems to support for IEEE 802.11b, 802.11g. So, should I switch to NG-Mixed mode for a better performance of my wifi network? Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I was just help you to find the information that someone else might need to answer the question. I suppose we need to know the make and model of your router as well...